# USB Flash Drive: Claimed Capacity 32GB, NAND Chip Capacity 256GB

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, usb-3, firmware

As stated in the title, I have a Lexar 32GB USB 3.0 flash drive that has a 256GB Nand Chip, but the claimed capacity is a mere 32GB. Is it possible to unlock at least half of this space that I am pretty sure is there in the case of bits going bad? The nand chip is labeled "5EC2D" and the Micron Technology FBGA code is "NW657", which refers to a 256 GB chip. If we need the controller chip number, I can possibly get it out. Here is a link to the Micron Page. 
https://www.micron.com/parts/nand-flash/mass-storage/mt29f256g08ceecbh6-12

And here are some badly taken photos of the flash drive.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pYnt.jpg

---

Edit:

I appologize for my stupidity, I completely missed the Gigabit size.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specs are 256 Gb which is 256 gigabits or 32 gigabytes.